# What piece (possibly by Chopin) begins with the scale e,f#,g#,a,b,c,d,e?

Tags: theory, piano, classical-music

My mom played a piece from memory that started with a run of this scale. She knew it from her youth and never remembered the title. She thought maybe Chopin, but I've unsuccessfully searched. She has passed away now, and I really want to learn this piece. I can only recall parts of the next line after the run.

Comment: Hi! That's A minor melodic ascending. I'm sure there's a universal question somewhere about identifying a scale, but I can't find it now.

Comment: This seems to be a reasonable description, although I personally cannot guarantee the accuracy: https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/1461

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about identifying pieces of music go on the Music Fans site rather than this one.

Comment: Tricia, I've rewritten the title of your question based on the body of your post. However, if your intention is just to identify the name of the scale (rather than the piece it came from) my changes can be easily rolled back. (I would also remove my vote to move the question to a different site. See the comment above in that regard.)

Comment: Aaron - you rewrote a perfectly clear and reasonable question and now the two replies now don't make sense. Could you please change the question back to how it was originally phrased.